# Creating button in excel to call popularity trends of a Sharepoint page

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, spreadsheet

What I'm trying to do: I have a list of webpages in an Excel spreadsheet that documents all pages in a SharePoint. I want to create a VB script that will call the Popularity Trends from each page separately. So say I have ten pages listed. I want ten separate buttons on the spreadsheet.

While I still need to work on the coding itself, I'm having issues finding what I need to from SharePoint. I'm not sure if I have the right permissions either. I have been searching for the Guid, unsuccessfully.  For the code itself, what would be the best way to call the popularity trend? I have searched for two days trying to find how SharePoint calls the popularity trends to try to mimic that in my VB code, but I come up pretty empty in that area as well. Below is some code I found online that I will try to manipulate (yes I realize this is for JIRA) (found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/832507-open-webpage-via-vba.html))…

```
    Sub GenerateJIRAData()
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://jira5/sr/jira.issueviews:searchrequest-excel-current-fields/12927/SearchRequest-12927.xls?os_username=MYJIRALOGINID&os_password=MYJIRAPASSWORD&tempMax=5000"
    Application.SendKeys ("{Tab}{Enter}")
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink URL
    ChDir "J:\Build and Release\Release Statistics"
    SendKeys ("Y") 'Suppress "Overwite" prompt
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "J:\Build and Release\Release Statistics\B+R SUPBARS Raw Data.xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you should research web page scraping using VBA.

Comment: Checking it out now!